# Is it required to multiply sourceSize by Screen.devicePixelRatio?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

[This property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-image.html#sourceSize-prop).

Is it required to multiply `sourceSize.width` and `sourceSize.height` by [Screen.devicePixelRatio](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-screen.html#devicePixelRatio-attached-prop), or is it already managed automatically by `Qt`?

I.e. if I set [width and height properties](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#height-prop) to 1000 then the real image size would be 1000x1000 physical pixels on normal displays and at least 2000x2000 physical pixels on Retina displays.

Is the same applied to `sourceSize.width` and `sourceSize.height` properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this portion of the code, I'd say that the sourceSize is then scaled (https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/quick/items/qquickimagebase.cpp.html#263) in these two cases: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/quick/items/qquickimagebase.cpp.html#_ZN22QQuickImageBasePrivate22updateDevicePixelRatioEd (or probably when you have a @2x file).

This seems to be confirmed by testing:

```
Window {
    width: 1920
    height: 1080
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Image {
        id: testImage
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: "file:///..."
        sourceSize.width: 1920
        sourceSize.height: 1080
    }
}
```

When pixel ratio is 2, image is rendered in lower quality for pngs with file:// scheme.

Comment: OK, probably. Can you answer on this then? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66829575/image-size-vs-sourcesize-strange-things

Comment: By reading your other question, I checked Qt code better and I had to fix my answer. It seems to work differently for PNG files with file:// scheme. Previous answer was partially incorrect. image scheme seems to work differently.

Comment: I'm using data:// scheme there, not file:// one.

Comment: My understanding is that data is treated like file in the link I posted. So it seems that device pixel ratio of 1 remains: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/quick/items/qquickimagebase.cpp.html#246.