# Image size vs sourceSize strange things

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

We had a strange problem with blurred images under Retina displays. Left part of the image - before, right one - after the fix.

[image]

Our QML code was using this code to show images:

```
Image {
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        sourceSize.width: 25
        sourceSize.height: 25
        source: preview.url
    }
```

I've tried to multiply `sourceSize` by `Screen.devicePixelRatio` - images became bigger so they did not fit their places.

Then I've replaced `sourceSize.width` with just `width` and the same for `height`. So:

```
Image {
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        width: 25
        height: 25
        source: preview.url
    }
```

And it works fine now.

My questions are:

1. Is it required to multiply `sourceSize` by `devicePixelRatio`? Or is it managed automatically? It seems that it is managed automatically for PNG and NOT managed for SVG.
2. If it is already managed automatically for PNG (these images preview.url are PNGs) then why was it blurred? The original PNG image is of size 64x64 pixels.
3. Why did images become bigger after I've multiplied `sourceSize` by `devicePixelRatio`?

**Addition #1**. I'm using `data://` scheme in images' URLs. I.e.

```
QString url("data:");
url += imageMimeType;
url += ";base64,";
url += imageData.toBase64();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While referring to the other answer I gave you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66828301/is-it-required-to-multiply-sourcesize-by-screen-devicepixelratio/66829397#66829397), my understanding of the Qt code is that, outside from the cases described [here](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/quick/items/qquickimagebase.cpp.html#_ZN22QQuickImageBasePrivate22updateDevicePixelRatioEd), Qt does no scale that value. So my understanding seems to be the opposite of what you state in 1. What evidences led you to that statement?

Assuming this concept is correct (I may be incorrect), the reason for point 2, would be that Qt is loading a size that would be appropriate for 1x scaling. But for higher factors, there is a quality loss. If you are on retina, then you should adjust that value, or provide the @2x version.

As for point 3, the reason is probably in the docs: "if the width and height properties are not specified, the Image automatically uses the size of the loaded image". So if you double the size of the loaded image, you double the size of the element, as you are not setting width and height explicitly.

Setting width and height solves the problem because the image is loaded in full size, so it can draw with proper quality after the scaling.

Hope someone else can correct me if my understanding of Qt code is wrong.